# Adding += support to datetime.time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

Python's `datetime.time` class is missing the functionality of `+=` with `datetime.timedelta`. I'm attempting to remedy this by creating a derived class `Time`. I then use the `datetime` `+=` and get the `datetime.time()`.

However, I can't figure out how to then transfer the parent class values. I've tried to implement a `copy` method, as shown below but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.time' objects is not writable
```

My current implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

class Time(time):
    def copy(self,other):
        self.hour = other.hour
        self.minute = other.minute
        self.second = other.second
        self.microsecond = other.microsecond

    def __add__(self,other):
        if isinstance(other,timedelta):
            dt = toDatetime(self)
            dt += other
            t = Time()
            t.copy(dt.time())
            return t
```

How can I copy the parent class's values? Also, is there a better way for me to get `+=` support for the equivalent of `datetime.time` and I am just going about this all wrong?

Comment: `datetime.time()` objects don't support arithmetic with `timedelta` because they don't have a *date component* to handle overflow. What would the result of `time(23, 59, 59) + timedelta(hours=1)` be for example?

Comment: Next to that, `datetime.time()` objects are *immutable*.

Comment: I see. So the immutability is the brick wall I am running into here. Looks like I'll have to implement it a different way.

Comment: Why not just pass in the components (hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds) to the constructor? `Time(dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond)`

Comment: Great idea! That works. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a copy, pass in the time components *to the constructor*:

```
t = Time(dt.hour, dt.minute, dt.second, dt.microsecond)
```

`datetime.time()` objects are otherwise immutable; you could use their [`time.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.replace) to create a new instance with specific components replaced, but since you are constructing a new subclass instance *anyway*, just passing in the components is easier.